# length() doesn't work in aggregate function using dot notation

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a large dataframe made up of both factor and numeric variables (numeric variables contain NA's).  I would like to find the number of observations of multiple numeric variables for different levels of one of the factor variables.  Instead of treating each numeric variable separately, I am trying to use the aggregate function with either dot notation or cbind to denote the numeric variables I would like grouped and counted using length().  However, when I do this aggregate gives the same number of observations for each variable, which I know is wrong.  Is there something about aggregate and length that doesn't work for multiple variables?

Here is a simple example that illustrates the problem... var1 should have n=3 in all groups, which it does when I treat it on it's own, but with dot notation or cbind it just assumes the n values of var2.

```
    df <- data.frame(group=c("a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c"), var1=1:9, var2=c(1,2,3,NA,5,6,7,8,9))
    aggregate(var1 ~ group, df, length) 
    aggregate(var2 ~ group, df, length) 
    aggregate(. ~ group, df, length)
    aggregate(cbind(var1,var2) ~ group, df, length)
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this helps:

```
df <- data.frame(group=c("a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c"),
                 var1=1:9, var2=c(1,2,3,NA,5,6,7,8,9))

with(df, length(cbind(var1, var2)))

> with(df, length(cbind(var1, var2)))
[1] 18
```

`length()` treats `cbind(var1, var2)` as a matrix, which is just a vector with dimensions, hence you get the length reported as `prod(nrow(mat), ncol(mat))` where `mat` is the resulting matrix.

Ideally you'd use `nrow()` instead of `length()`, but perhaps more widely applicable is the `NROW()` function, which will treat a vector as a 1-column matrix for purposes of evaluating the function. `nrow()` won't work for a vector input

```
> nrow(1:10)
NULL
```

E.g. try these:

```
aggregate(cbind(var1,var2) ~ group, df, NROW)
aggregate(var1 ~ group, df, NROW)

> aggregate(cbind(var1,var2) ~ group, df, NROW)
  group var1 var2
1     a    2    2
2     b    3    3
3     c    3    3
> aggregate(var1 ~ group, df, NROW)
  group var1
1     a    3
2     b    3
3     c    3
```

and as you have `NA`, you probably don't want the incomplete cases removed, which would happen by default. This is seen above and hence why the number of rows for group `a` is 2. For that add `na.action = na.pass` to the call:

```
aggregate(cbind(var1,var2) ~ group, df, NROW, na.action = na.pass)

> aggregate(cbind(var1,var2) ~ group, df, NROW, na.action = na.pass)
  group var1 var2
1     a    3    3
2     b    3    3
3     c    3    3
```

The issues is that in building up the data frame to pass to `aggregate.data.frame`, the usual model frame generation process takes place and `aggregate.formula` has the `na.action` argument set to `na.omit` by default - which is standard behaviour in modelling functions that use formula interfaces.

If you want to count the number of non-`NA` values per variable then you need a completely different approach, perhaps using `is.na()`, as in

```
foo <- function(x) sum(!is.na(x))
aggregate(cbind(var1,var2) ~ group, df, foo, na.action = na.pass)

> aggregate(cbind(var1,var2) ~ group, df, foo, na.action = na.pass)
  group var1 var2
1     a    3    2
2     b    3    3
3     c    3    3
```

Which works by counting the number of non-`NA` values through coercion of first `TRUE` -> `FALSE` via `!` and then resulting `TRUE`s are converted to `1` and `FALSE`s to `0`, which `sum()` then adds for us.

Comment: Hi Gavin!  Thanks for the explanation.  I don't want the NAs included in my counting or for any of my other functions (min, max, mean, etc) for that matter.  I see that 'foo' works, but don't understand why you use 'sum'.  Shouldn't that add up all the non-NAs?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your text below the code.  Ok, I understand how this works.  However, I also want to use aggregate with cbind or dot notation to apply other functions to my groupings (e.g. min, max, mean, sd).  Just adding in na.action=na.pass doesn't work.  Any advice?  Btw... this is Claire from the course you gave at Mac!

Comment: @CJO Hi Claire! Those functions you list all have an `na.rm` argument which will ignore any `NA` whilst doing the computation instead of returning `NA`. You pass additional arguments to functions via the `...` argument. Hence `aggregate(cbind(var1,var2) ~ group, df, mean, na.action = na.pass, na.rm = TRUE)` will work. Just switch out `mean` and replace with the other functions you mentioned.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Gavin! It's really amazing how long one can spend trying to figure this out.